# What numerical scheme could I use to solve this integral equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, python

I have the following equation which I would like to solve numerically (python) but I am not sure what scheme could be used. Any suggestions?

$$\phi_{2} = \int_{0}^{^{\phi_{1}}} \frac{r_{1}(\phi_{1})}{A-r_{1}(\phi_{1})}d\phi_{1}$$ where A is a constant = $$r_{1} + r_{2}$$

$$\phi_{1}$$ and $$\phi_{2}$$ are in  polar coordinates.

$$r_{1}(\phi_{1})$$ will be a non-intersecting smooth and closed curve.

Comment: You need a different symbol for the limit of integration than for the variable of integration. Also what is the argument of $\phi_2$?

Comment: If you don't know $r(\Phi)$ you can not solve it.

Comment: Besides that, does $r_1$ have any weird properties? Singularities, points where it equals $A$, etc.? If not then this is just an ODE after you differentiate both sides, assuming I am understanding the question correctly.

Comment: @Ian: thanks for the good questions. I have updated my post accordingly which I hope is sufficient.

Comment: So a numerical scheme that solves ODE's would be sufficient?

Comment: $r_1(\phi_1)$ is not a closed curve.

Comment: @Doug: The requirement holds, so I deleted the example. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Ah.  Perhaps $(\phi_1,r_1)$ are polar coordinates.  In that case, I can see how that could be a closed curve.

Comment: I still don't understand the structure of the problem. Is it "find $g$ such that $g(x)=\int_0^x f(y) dy$, where $f$ is a given smooth function on the circle"? If so then you can just solve $g'=f,g(0)=0$. If it is something else then you need to revise the question. (For example maybe $f$ is not precisely specified because $A$ is part of the solution, and you would like to demand that $g$ is also smooth on the circle.)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is simply one possible approach that should work, although there may be more efficient means.  The trapezoidal method is in general good with periodic functions.  Let's say you know the function $\phi_2(t)$ and you want to solve this integral equation for $\phi_1$ on a set of $n+1$ grid points $0,h,\dots,nh$.  Then,  I would suggest the following:

0. Initialize $t = h$, $i = 0$.
1. Evaluate $\phi_2(t)$.
2. integrate $I(T) = \int_{0}^{T} \frac{r_1(t)}{A-r_1(t)}dt$ using trapezoidal rule.
3. update $T$ until you find a $T$ such that $I(T) = \phi_2(t)$ within precision.  Then, save $\phi_1(t) = T$.
4. $i \leftarrow i+1$.
5. $t\leftarrow t+ih$
6. Go to step 1.

To speed things up a bit, replace the lower limit of integration each time with $(i-1)h$.

Comment: Ok that looks a good start but what about A? Is this not an unknown when we integrate I(T)

Comment: I assumed that because $A$ is a constant that it is known.

Comment: Iv discovered that the constant  A= r1+r2